# Hide movieclips which playing on different frames with ActionScript3 AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

[project file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Bs_fu3Q6U3UmgxNGhmQzFCUXc/view?usp=sharing)I am new to AS3

I have 3 movieclips on 3 layers first one on frame(1,layer1) second on frame 2 from layer 2) and the last is on frame3 from layer3).

The problem I face is that only first movieclip which is on frame 1 disappears
but the others stay visible. I want to hide all of them when a button is clicked.

This is what I've tried :

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler3); 

function mouseDownHandler3(event:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
    mc1.visible=false; 
    mc2.visible=false; 
    mc3.visible=false;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: please, add your code that what you are doing so we can help you.

Comment: btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler3);
function mouseDownHandler3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 
    mc1.visible=false;
 mc2.visible=false;
 mc3.visible=false;}

Comment: In AS3 you can apply actions to the available objects. At the frame 1 you cannot access things that does not exist yet.

Comment: Thanks Organis
so is there anyway to apply the idea?

Comment: Screw frames, largely.

Comment: Why not keep all 3 movieclips and all code on frame 1 only? You can use  `visible=true` or even `addChild(someMC)` to make things appear without going to new frames (afterall you are making a program not an animation)...

Comment: i have attached the project file....i want every single small rectangle to put in the correct place corresponding withe the correct number when i click next/prev button...Any help?....thanks a lot

Comment: Also i want to show/hide these small rectangles when i clicK btn(MC)

Comment: Could you use a 4th frame to goto when you press the button it would remove all the other mc not on that frame]